# How to extract data to outfile in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
select * into outfile 'D:/mysql/upload/po.txt' From country;
```

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the
> --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I got mysql server 8.

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 
my.ini changed  secure-file-priv="D:/mysql/upload"
```

How to extract data to outfile in MySQL?

Comment: have you restartet the server? and checked alsp the error log

Comment: Yes, command RESTART; helped extract query to txt file. Thanks